# Microsoft 365 Group: Owner unable to Update Group

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, distribution-lists

I have a Microsoft 365 Group owner who is unable to update their group. In searching for a fix, I found that none of the solutions worked for me. The user was confirmed as added to the group (`recipients> groups> group> Ownership`) , and the policies allowed users to update groups that they are a part of (`Permissions> User Roles> Default Role Assignment Policy> MyDistributionGroupMembership: Enabled`).

Is there a permissions limitation that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the user account under `Exchange> recipients> shared`. I converted the mailbox back to a regular mailbox, had the user test, and the user was able to successfully update the group mailbox membership.

Answer (score 0):

I am glad to know that the issue has been resolved, please mark the helpful replies as answers, this will make answer searching in the forum easier and be beneficial to other community members as well.

In addition, we also could check shared mailbox limitations in Office 365:
https://msexperttalk.com/understanding-shared-mailbox-limitations-office-365/